# Sourcing for low power stepper motor driver assembly. Which is best cost and host software wise?

Tags: ethernet, stepper-motor, tcp-ip

For small batch production I am looking for small low cost product. Need it to be network controlled (Ethernet TCP/IP) with open documentation. The current is about 1..2..3 Ampere, voltage 24..48V. Also nice to have just 1..4 axes and DIN rail mount.

Problem is, that everything I can find is serial port controlled or modular blocks with 2-3 accessories with proprietary software and lot of unnecessary features, making software part complicated and requiring for host PC to be equipped with extra $100 I/O ports.

Comment: I would not call a 3A/48V, 4-axis stepper controller "low power".  Your requirements (Ethernet/DIN/motor control) seem fairly disparate so I would be surprised to find a single unit that does all that.  By "$100 I/O ports" do you mean an RS485 card?

Comment: Yes. Those RS485 cards are annoyance from software point of view. Cards like this are usually small batches no matter how big a manifacturer is. And so, the quality of drivers is always poor. for this reason alone, its worthy to use TCP/IP with zero proprietary software on PC host side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [Arduino Mega RepRap Pololu Carrier](http://ultimachine.com/ramps)  (RAMPS) is compatible with the [Arduino Ethernet shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield). The RAMPS board doesn't seem to use mega pins 50, 51, 52 and 10, which is what the shield page says it uses. I've never actually tried this myself though. The Pololu drivers can do about 1A and up to 35V.

Comment: Great. Looks like more or less mainstream piece with very opened platform.

Answer (score 1):

[This work?](http://www.amci.com/stepper-motor-control/nexus-stepper-motor-controller.asp)

The command/control layout is right in the data sheet, looks like it just responds to any packets sent to it.  Driver is a separate piece.

Comment: Yes, I know about this AMCI network piece with extra drives. But the price is prohibitive. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Cheap, Fast, Correct...choose 2.